SST throws "Cannot find package 'next' imported from /var/task/index.mjs"
I created a default Nextjs sst script and deployed it, but got this error message.
"Cannot find package 'next' imported from /var/task/index.mjs"

My SST script is inside an app from a monorepo:
apps
   website
      sst.config.ts
      package.json
      // Nextjs and other files

I'm not running SST ion. What could be the reason or where can I look for? Been stucked on this for the past two days.
The same project deploys successfully on a non-monorepo environment, but this error happens only in this scenario so I'm thinking that maybe is a missing monorepo config? I don't really know.
